# List from fields of elements

Tags: c#, performance, linq, element

I can turn my dictionary `Dictionary<long,MyObj>` to a list with `.Values`, where `MyObj` has the `Vector3` field named `position`.

I would like to have a list of the positions (the value type): `MyObj.position`, like so: `List<Vector3> positions`.

Performance is critical.

Is there a way to achieve this in C# with LINQ or otherwise other than?

```
foreach e in myDict
   mylist.Add(e.Value.position)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: `yourDictionary.Select(kvp => kvp.Value.position).ToList()`?

Comment: Why the downvotes? So far I would just iterate and construct the list everytime. Thanks for the Select tip, CodeCaster! I assumed select was only for filtering and that it were not as efficient as it could be. Is it the best way?

Comment: How do you define efficiency?  The Select is O(n) because it has to traverse all of the elements in your dictionary, but that's by design.  If you don't want to take the performance hit, work with the dictionary directly.

Comment: Downvotes: Probably because the question is not so clear, and you don't provide any of your code. <del>(MCVE)</del> Just to make clear, I did not downvote, I just got here.

Comment: @PedroGaspar: MCVEs only apply to troubleshooting questions.

Comment: I guess there's no way around traversing it since the positions are not contiguous in memory. I guess that's as good as it can get.

Comment: similar to CodeCaster you could do a search on just the values yourDictionary.Values.Select(obj => obj.position).ToList().

Comment: Is that faster or just clearer, @sr28 ?

Comment: Only way to be sure is to time it. Create a stop watch and run both

Comment: I recommend testing the time yourself, but LINQ is generally few time slower than loops. `foreach (var v in myDict.Values)` might be a bit faster. For faster than that you might need custom dictionary or changing the approach/algorithm. But before all that, make sure that is the part of the code that needs to be optimised..

Comment: I would agree with Slai. The foreach approach is probably faster. I'll see if I can get some times.

Comment: Thanks for the timing. I'll reproduce it on my context (mobile) to see if it still holds. I have some more complex design alternatives in mind if it is still too slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, using the code below:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var stopwatch1 = new Stopwatch();
        var dictionaryTest = GetDictionary(1000);

        stopwatch1.Start();

        var results = dictionaryTest.Values.Select(x => x.Position).ToList();

        stopwatch1.Stop();

        var stopwatch2 = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch2.Start();

        var results2 = dictionaryTest.Select(obj => obj.Value.Position).ToList();

        stopwatch2.Stop();

        var stopwatch3 = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch3.Start();

        var myList = new List<double>();

        foreach (var pair in dictionaryTest)
        {
            myList.Add(pair.Value.Position);
        }

        stopwatch3.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("results1: " + stopwatch1.Elapsed);
        Console.WriteLine("results2: " + stopwatch2.Elapsed);
        Console.WriteLine("results3: " + stopwatch3.Elapsed);
        Console.Read();
    }

    public static Dictionary<long, MyUser> GetDictionary(int numberOfRows)
    {
        var d = new Dictionary<long, MyUser>();

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++)
        {
            d.Add(1000 + i, new MyUser { Age = 10 + i, Position = 100.01 + i });
        }

        return d;
    }
```

This brought back:

[image]

So foreach looks like the quickest of the 3 proposed on my machine. Worth testing yourself though.

With 'optimize code' selected:

[image]

Comment: Just to be sure, did you compile with optimization flags?

Comment: @quimnuss - updated with optimize flag selected. Same result though.